# A new drive gets a lot of space allocated after formatting - why?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a VM hosted on a Hyper-V server that's acting as an RDS host. I have added a disk of size 4 GB in order to place a paging file to it. When I format it, its capacity is reported as 3.97 GB, but once I assign it a letter, the free space gets shrinked by a whole 12% to 3.45 GB. I then run `defrag s: /a /v`, where "s:" is that drive's letter, it reports the following:

```
Microsoft Drive Optimizer
Copyright (c) 2013 Microsoft Corp.

Invoking slab consolidation on Swap (S:)...

The operation completed successfully.

Post Defragmentation Report:

    Volume Information:
            Volume size                 = 3,99 GB
            Cluster size                = 64 KB
            Used space                  = 23,87 MB
            Free space                  = 3,97 GB

    Slab Consolidation:
            Space efficiency            = 100%
            Potential purgable slabs    = 0
```

That is, the space is actually released, but it gets immediately allocated back. I wonder what causes this? I have encountered that Recycle Bin properties were set to about 540MB for that disk, so I deactivated that setting to "Don't put files to recycle bin" for disk S:. Still the problem persists. What else could allocate that space?

UPDATE: If I remove the drive letter then format the drive again, the free space is listed correctly as 3.97 GB ($Mft most likely taking most space), but as soon as I assign it a letter I lose 500 MB space, even if I already set recycle bin volume for the drive. I cannot reboot the OS on that VM to check if that would fix the problem, but I have not encountered such behavior before - maybe recycle bin's still allocating its 540MB of default value just because it didn't refresh its settings by a reboot. Can someone confirm the issue, then?

Comment: A 4 GB disk with 64 KB clusters ... did you format it as FAT32? Can you see any files that are being put on it? Did you check the size of the recycle bin folder if it exists?

Comment: @Seth No it's NTFS formatted with manual cluster size setting (I'm intending to store there a pagefile and that's all). Recycle bin folder size is 129b. Also there'll be an update in a minute.

Comment: Do you have quotas set up? Try running the TreeSize Pro trial as admin and see what it reports. Also look at the output of `dir` in Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Windows is set to manage the virtual memory automatically. Perhaps it is just quick to create a page file on the new disk?

Check if there is any hidden system files in the root of the drive by going into View -> Options and set it like this:

[image]

In my case, I have the `hiberfile.sys`, `pagefile.sys` and `swapfile.sys` located there.

Comment: This was present, and prior to me putting there page file there were only `$RECYCLE.BIN` folder with a single file in it, totaling 129 bytes allocated. But, the amount of free space was less than full capacity by about 500 MB.

Comment: I tried to duplicate the issue, but my environment is slightly different (VMWare ESX 6.0, Windows 2008 R2). It allocates 50 MB but no more..

Comment: Well, there might be issues with RDSH role and 2012R2 guest. I don't think that hypervisor would matter here, but guest OS and role might alter a frikking lot. After all, a DC+RDSH is a deadly combo XD

Comment: Windows will not put the page file on random drives. It’s on the system drive by default.

Comment: @DanielB still it was worth checking if I'd enabled listing for system protected files.